# "Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined". error in AngularJs. Does anyone have a solution?

Tags: angularjs, q

In my service "customerService" I am injecting the $q object which exposes the deferred object. In my function "getCustomers" I am trying to retrieve the deferred object but I receive an error:  "Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined" when I run the $q.defer() method. I have already looked at similar solutions on stackoverflow but none were adequate. What could be the cause of this error?

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

//creates sql database connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
        host:"localhost",
        database: "customer_manager"
    }
);

angular.module('app')
.service('customerService', ['$q','$http', CustomerService]);

function CustomerService($q){
    return {
        getCustomers: getCustomers
    }
}


function getCustomers($q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    connection.query(query, function(err, res){
        if(err) deferred.reject(err);
        deferred.resolve(res);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issues:
1. You have already injected $q service which registering service so there is no need to explicit pass in the function arguments.
2. In case of angular service, you will have to associate all exposing APIs to **this** instead return that. Else it will not work. We return exposing APIs in case of angular factory.

### Correct Code is attached below:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('customerService', ['$q','$http', CustomerService]);

function CustomerService($q, $http){
    this.getCustomers = function(){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       var query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
       connection.query(query, function(err, res){
          if(err) deferred.reject(err);
          deferred.resolve(res);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

This will resolve your issues.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Excellent answer, I have implemented the code as above and the $q object is being injected however, Angular is still giving me the error that the defer property of the $q object is undefined. Any further ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This is the working piece of copy. I am not sure why not working at your end. Try with 
angular.module('app', [])
.service('customerService', ['$q','$http', CustomerService]) and see if works.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `$q` as an argument to your `getCustomers` function. `$q` is automatically available in all the functions in your service.

Also, change `CustomerService($q)` to `CustomerService($q, $http)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function CustomerService($q){
    return {
        getCustomers: getCustomers($q)
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if your code can answer the question, it's interesting if you can give some explanation to the OP showing what's wrong or something like that.