# Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to build an angular service that will be used by a controller in my application.  I am trying to use $q to wait for execution of a function within my service to complete before continuing in my controller.  However, I cannot get angular to inject/recognize $q.  Here is the relevant portion of code.

```
angular.module('gservice', [])
.factory('gservice', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($http, $location, $q) {
    // Initialize Variables
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    // Service our factory will return
    var googleMapService = {};

    // Array of locations obtained from API calls
    var locations = [];
    var photos = [];
    var places = [];
    var placeTags = [];

    // Selected Location (intialize to center of America)
    var selectedLat = 39.50;
    var selectedLong = -98.35;

    var map;

    // Functions
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    googleMapService.getPhotos = function() {
        return photos;
    }
    // Refresh the Map with new data.  Function will take new latitiude and longitude coordinates.
    googleMapService.refresh = function (latitude, longitude, $q) {
        // Clears the holding array of locations
        locations = [];

        // Set the selected lat and long equal to the ones provided on the refresh() call
        selectedLat = latitude;
        selectedLong = longitude;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var groupHeight1 = document.getElementById('myFormGroup1').clientHeight;
        var groupHeight2 = document.getElementById('myFormGroup2').clientHeight;
        var groupHeight3 = document.getElementById('myFormGroup3').clientHeight;
        var submitHeight = document.getElementById('submit').clientHeight;

        // Perform AJAX call to get all of the records in the db.
        $http.get('/trips')
            .then(function (success) {

            // Convert the results into Google Map Format
            locations = convertLocationsToPoints(success);

            // Initialize map
            initializeMap(latitude, longitude);

            //  Initialize route
            if(locations.length > 0) {
                initializeDirections();
                ;
            }
        }, function (error) {
                console.log('Error' + error);

        });

    };
```

Whenever I run my application, I receive the error: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined.  I have read [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418121/cannot-read-property-defer-of-undefined-error-in-angularjs-does-anyone-hav) but most of the issues have been due to improper dependency injection.  I believe I have injected $q correctly using the inline annotation technique.  I have read that  passing the parameter explicitly is unnecessary given the inline annotation.  I have tried with and without the explicit parameter to no avail.  SOS!

**EDIT 1:**

@avat

Ah I see.  I did not realize that the array elements are matched against function parameters!  After editing my code per your suggestion, I no longer receive a null reference when I make a call on $q *outside* of the refresh function. However, I still receive the null reference when making calls *within* the refresh function.  How can I pass this dependency to the function of the service object (googleMapService) that I would like to return?

Comment: No, injection does not look right. Elements in the array are matched against the function parameters, which in your case gives: $http parameter receives the $q value, $location parameter receives the $rootScope value and $q parameters receives null.

There may be other problems as well about this service, for instance I don't see the function actually returning the service.

Comment: thank you.  I posted a follow-up after implementing your suggestions.

Comment: I don't know where and how the refresh() function is called, but the way it is defined "$q" can only have a value inside the function if the caller passes it as a 3rd parameter. Not sure what the final purpose is, but I think you rather need to use "$q" as passed to the service, not the refresh() function. In other words, don't declare it as a parameter to refresh()...